# Re-writing Common Table Expression (CTE) to Subquery to make a compatable PowerBI DirectQuery

Tags: sql-server, subquery, common-table-expression, powerbi-desktop

I have the following MS SQL Server query that when run in PowerBI throws an error as CTEs are not supported by DirectQuery.

```
;WITH Daily_Report_CTE
AS
  (
    SELECT WazeUpdateTime_PST, Name, Length, Time, TimePeriod =
    (
      CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 5 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 11 THEN 'Morning'
        WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 11 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 17 THEN 'Mid-Day'
        WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 23 THEN 'Evening'
        ELSE 'Overnight'
      END
     )
    FROM Repository_Archive.DataManagement_Ops_AllAccess.vw_Waze_TVT_ParsedJSON_Routes
    WHERE (DATEPART(dy, WazeUpdateTime_PST) BETWEEN DATEPART(dy,DateAdd(DD,-21,( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))) and DATEPART(dy,( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time')))
    AND (DATENAME(weekday, WazeUpdateTime_PST)) = DATENAME(weekday, ( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))
    AND Name IN ('I-105 to UL', 'La Cienega to UL', '405-La Tijera-Sepulveda to UL', 'Manchester to UL', 'Howard Hughes to UL', 'Lincoln to UL', 'Lincoln-Manchester to UL')
   )

SELECT WazeUpdateTime_PST, Name, Length, Time, TimePeriod, 
  Color = 
    (
     CASE
      WHEN Time > PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Time)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name, TimePeriod)
          THEN 'Red'
      WHEN Time > PERCENTILE_CONT(0.6) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Time)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name, TimePeriod)
          THEN 'Yellow'
      ELSE 'Green'
     END
     )
FROM Daily_Report_CTE
```

A common workaround is apparently rewriting CTEs as subqueries within the main query. 
I am not the most knowledgeable when it comes to SQL Server or SQL as a whole and it was a struggle to build a functioning query using the CTE.

How should I go about re-writing this as a subquery?

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you can just move the CTE into the FROM

```
SELECT WazeUpdateTime_PST, Name, Length, Time, TimePeriod, 
  Color = 
    (
     CASE
      WHEN Time > PERCENTILE_CONT(0.95) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Time)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name, TimePeriod)
          THEN 'Red'
      WHEN Time > PERCENTILE_CONT(0.6) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Time)  
    OVER (PARTITION BY Name, TimePeriod)
          THEN 'Yellow'
      ELSE 'Green'
     END
     )
FROM (
        SELECT WazeUpdateTime_PST, Name, Length, Time, TimePeriod =
            (
              CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 5 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 11 THEN 'Morning'
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 11 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 17 THEN 'Mid-Day'
                WHEN DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) >= 17 AND DATEPART(hour, WazeUpdateTime_PST) < 23 THEN 'Evening'
                ELSE 'Overnight'
              END
             )
            FROM Repository_Archive.DataManagement_Ops_AllAccess.vw_Waze_TVT_ParsedJSON_Routes
            WHERE (DATEPART(dy, WazeUpdateTime_PST) BETWEEN DATEPART(dy,DateAdd(DD,-21,( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))) and DATEPART(dy,( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time')))
            AND (DATENAME(weekday, WazeUpdateTime_PST)) = DATENAME(weekday, ( GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Pacific Standard Time'))
            AND Name IN ('I-105 to UL', 'La Cienega to UL', '405-La Tijera-Sepulveda to UL', 'Manchester to UL', 'Howard Hughes to UL', 'Lincoln to UL', 'Lincoln-Manchester to UL')
     ) A
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this works! I don't know if this is or is not a dumb question, but what is the significance of the trailing "A"?

Comment: @Errata-ds A sub query requires an alias