# Left Join also working in direct query in Power BI

Tags: join, powerbi

This is only sample case, my original table is more complex.

Table A

| SchoolId | ClubId | ChildID | TeacherId | AttendanceDate | IsPresent |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 |
| A | 1 | 3 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 11 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |
| B | 2 | 22 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 |
| B | 2 | 33 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 |

Table B

| ChildID | TeacherId | CreateOn | IsPresent | ReasonId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 23-MAY-2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 22 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 2 |
| 33 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 3 |

Table C

| ReasonId | ReasonMaster |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Health |
| 2 | Social |
| 3 | Unknown |

I want the left join result like this :

| SchoolId | ClubId | ChildID | TeacherId | AttendanceDate | IsPresent | ReasonId | ReasonMaster |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |  |  |
| A | 1 | 2 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 2 | Social |
| A | 1 | 3 | 1 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |  |  |
| B | 2 | 11 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 1 |  |  |
| B | 2 | 22 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 2 | Social |
| B | 2 | 33 | 2 | 22-MAY-2022 | 0 | 3 | Unknown |

Here are my cases:

I only want to retrieve the latest data from table B based on create on column on the table B to the table A. Because there is a duplicate input by users. for instance in the table B child Id= 2 & Teacher Id=1.
I only need to retrieve the the data if the status in the table A, column IsPresent=0
There is an additional data from table C which reason master.

I try this Query, but CTE function not working in Power BI.

```
;with MaxCreate as (Select ChildID,TeacherID,Max(CreateOn) as MaxCreateOn
    from TableB
    group by ChildID,TeacherID)
,LatestCreate as (select TableB.ChildID, TableB.TeacherId, TableB.CreateOn, TableB.IsPresent, TableB.ReasonId
    from TableB
    inner join MaxCreate
    on TableB.ChildID = MaxCreate.ChildID
    and TableB.TeacherId = MaxCreate.TeacherId
    and TableB.CreateOn = MaxCreate.MaxCreateOn)
Select 
     TableA.SchoolId
    ,TableA.ClubId
    ,TableA.ChildID
    ,TableA.TeacherId
    ,TableA.AttendanceDate
    ,TableA.IsPresent
    ,LatestCreate.ReasonId
    ,TableC.ReasonMaster
From  TableA
Left join LatestCreate
on TableA.ChildID = LatestCreate.ChildID
and TableA.TeacherID = LatestCreate.TeacherID
left join TableC
on LatestCreate.ReasonId = TableC.ReasonId
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Left Join and only retrieve the latest record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72390291/left-join-and-only-retrieve-the-latest-record)

Comment: Do not repost questions, edit them. Your preveious version of this question was closed because it needed to pass review after improvement. Don't subvert site protocols. [Help]

Comment: Duplicate of [Re-writing Common Table Expression (CTE) to Subquery to make a compatable PowerBI DirectQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58532581/3404097) Please in code questions give a [mre]. [ask] [Help] Please before considering posting read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. Read the SO/SE search help. Google re googling/searching, including in Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se].